# AngularJS ng-options add another option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown select using AngularJS. In the controller, I get the value of $scope.items from an API. I want to add another option with value="0" as the first option. How to do it?

```
<select required class="form-control has-error" id="selected_item"
 ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items" name="selected_item"
 ng-model="selected_item" ng-change="selectItem()" ng-required="true">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an option element to the select or add it to your model

```
<select required class="form-control has-error" id="selected_item"
 ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items" name="selected_item"
 ng-model="selected_item" ng-change="selectItem()" ng-required="true">
    <option value="0"></option>
</select>
```